# How to achieve perstistence with ssh keys using ssh-add

Tags: server, ssh, remote-access, ssh-agent

I'm trying to make my ssh keys permanent. I tend to use crazy passwords and typing it in every time destroys workflow. I have two keys, one with to a remote server and one for github. I would like to have the keys persist across reboots.

If it helps, I'm running Ubuntu 19.10.

I have different keys for different hosts, and those are differentiated in `~/.ssh/config` like so:

```
Host github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github/github


Host <host ip>
     User <username>
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/ssh_key/ssh_key
```

I then changed permissions with `chmod 600` as recomended here:
[How to permanently add a private key with ssh-add on Ubuntu? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466626/how-to-permanently-add-a-private-key-with-ssh-add-on-ubuntu)

I also tried running `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa &>/dev/null` to `~/.profile` as suggested there, but that doesn't seem to persist across reboots.

I'd like to avoid using `ssh-add -K` as my understanding of the flag will store the private key in plaintext. If I am wrong please correct me.

What else can I try?

Comment: What do you mean by "make my ssh keys permanent"?

Comment: When I add an ssh key to the agent using `ssh-add`, I would like them to persist across reboots. I can't seem to find a reliable way of doing that.